# Where can I find a database on the masses of different galaxies?

Tags: galaxy, mass

I want to get the data for masses of galaxies, more information about them can only be helpful. Can anyone point me to a site where I can get this sort of information?

Comment: Hi Arcadio, there are many databases but galaxies are selected in many different ways, influencing their inferred masses. For instance, a database of sub-mm-selected galaxies will yield massive ellipticals, Lyman α emitters are typically not so massive, absorption studies tend to return small systems, etc. Also, it will be helpful if you mention which masses you're interested in: The total mass including their dark matter halos are often not reported, since this requires either dynamical measurements or some model. Stellar masses are more common, but don't include interstellar gas, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, I would suggest searching on [VizieR](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR) for catalogues of galaxies. E.g. select "Galaxies" in the "Astronomy" menu (on the right-hand side of the initial form) and put "Masses" in the "Find catalogs" search box (the upper one, the lower one is for searching by position which is less useful here).

In the results section, the elliptical icons on the right-hand side allow you to see roughly what the sky coverage is for the catalogue. Once you select a catalogue, you can take a look at what fields are there.